# Unable to load inMobi advertisement in iOS

Tags: ads, inmobi

I integrated inMobi ads in my iOS app but  response in going in :-

```
- (void)adView:(IMAdView *)adView didFailRequestWithError:(IMAdError *)error
{
}
```

My app is not released in App store , so cant provide URL. But want to test the app. Can I get test ads. Or something else I am doing wrong? Please tell me the possible solution?

Please reply fast. Thanx in Advance.

Comment: You can definitely test the ads out on your app before its on the app store. Are you testing it out on your device or on the simulator ?

Also, did you add the Property ID correctly? It'll be helpful if you could post some code too.